# Show data based in input value

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to display data from an API based on the value of an input, but before I even type something in the input box, it reads the value that is inside the box right after I type (in this case its undefined, because I haven't typed anything).

Here's what I tried to do:

```js
fetch("https://covid-19-coronavirus-statistics.p.rapidapi.com/v1/stats?country=" +
    countryInput.value, {
      "method": "GET",
      "headers": {
        "x-rapidapi-host": "covid-19-coronavirus-statistics.p.rapidapi.com",
        "x-rapidapi-key": "20438f9eb4mshb2a68ca50196b46p1d55a5jsn2dbdc2b012cd"
      }
    })
  .then(response => {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(data => {

      countryInput = inputElement.value
```

(the code keeps on)

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript, when you want to do something *when something else happens* (eg. when an input changes), you have to use an event listener.  Specifically for your case of triggering an AJAX request when an input's value changes, you'd likely need to listen for a "blur" or "change" event.

Fully explaining how events and event listeners work goes beyond the scope of Stack Overflow answer, but see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events for a complete explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you would listen to "change" event on the input field and fire the fetch function when it detects that a user has entered information.

Though it is worth mentioning that since a user will be typing out the name of the country, the callback function (the `fetch()`) will fire several times before they finish typing the name of a country especially if the country has a long name. Each time they enter a new letter the call to the API will fire, and most of the time it will return no results. This could be seen as wasteful of the API's resources.

It would be a better idea to provide a "submit" button, or wait until the user hits the enter key before sending the API call.

```js
function fetchTheDataFromTheApi(){
  fetch("https://covid-19-coronavirus-statistics.p.rapidapi.com/v1/stats?country=" + 
  countryInput.value, {
  "method": "GET",
  "headers": {
      "x-rapidapi-host": "covid-19-coronavirus-statistics.p.rapidapi.com",
      "x-rapidapi-key": "20438f9eb4mshb2a68ca50196b46p1d55a5jsn2dbdc2b012cd"
   }
   } )
   .then(response => {
  return response.json();
   })
  .then(data => {
    //do something with the data here like console.log it
  console.log(data)
  })
}

document.getElementById('countryInput').addEventListener("change", fetchTheDataFromTheApi)
```

```html
<input id="countryInput">
```